# Deployment of Spring petclinic to Bluemix Liberty

Tags: ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty, devops

I am trying to deploy Spring petclinic taken from

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic

It works without any issues on Tomcat and Jboss /wildfly but while deploying in Bluemix I am getting the following exception:

```
Error 500: javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter [dandelionFilter]: could not be initialized
```

Need to understand the root cause and if there is a fix .
Is it more of a Liberty feature issue? 
The use case is critical for a migration project.

Answer (score 1):

You can deploy this application using the Clound Foundry Java Buildpack.

Build the war file using Maven:

```
$ mvn package
```

That will create the `petclinic.war` file.

Use the Cloud Foundry cli to push the application:

```
$ cf push <app-name> -p petclinic.war -b https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack.git
```

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas how to move forward:

- Is it that particular filter that causes trouble, or is it just any filter? (what happens if you remove it from your web.xml file - will next filter throw the same error or will it start work)? If it is, the problem might be that you are using the wrong libs. It could for example be because libs are found in the wrong order, or that libs included in the different servers are different.
- Can you run your project locally using a WLP (WebSphere Liberty Profile) server (for example from within Eclipse)? For development purposes that server is available and free to use, and I suspect that you want to do that, so you can test and debug your work before pushing to Bluemix. If it works locally, chances are much hinger that it works when you push it.